# Regular expressioon for relative path in Windows

Tags: regex

I can't construct regular expressions so I am asking you for a help.
I need regular expression for the following type of strings, which are similar to Windows relative paths. It should accept only the following type of strings:

```
\some\another\path
\some\another\path\
some\another\path
some\another\path\
```

As can be seen it should accept paths with leading or trailing slashes (or both) as well as without them or one of them and there cannot be two slashes in a row. There also has to be at least one component of a path (not exactly three like in  the examples).

Comment: use `?` to make it optional.

Comment: Have you tried regexpal or rubular to construct your regex? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. I have this: `(\\{1}[^/:\*;\/\:\?<>\|]+)` but it requires slash as a first character.

Comment: do as @user3218114 said.

Comment: [Try this Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/QWbVc23ACf) but your requirements are too vague. Can there be spaces, numbers, underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: `^\\?([^\\/:*?<>|]+\\?)+$`

- Optionally start with a slash `^\\?`
- One or more occurrences of the group `(...)+`:

  - One or more path characters (on my PC it says not /:*?<>|) `[^\\/:*?<>|]+`
  - Optional trailing slash `\\?`
- End of string `$`